# How would I show function $f(x)=4x$ is Turing computable?

Tags: formal-languages, turing-machines, computability, automata, arithmetic

How to show $f: \mathbb{N} \to\mathbb{N}$ with $f(x)=4x$ where $x$ is in the set of natural numbers $x\in\mathbb{N}$) is Turing Computable?

My guess is obviously *there is a finite number of operations needed to reach a solution meaning it is Turing computable*.

Not sure how to prove this though! Can someone please expand?

Comment: Hint: Multiplying with 4 on binary encoded numbers is just adding two $0$s at the end of the number. I think you can build a TM for that task.

Comment: "Needing finite number of operations" is not a valid criterion. For instance, the halting oracle requires only finitely many operations for each $n$ (in fact, just one operation, which is either "write 0" or "write 1") – but of course the halting oracle is not computable. You need a *single set* of finite operations which works correctly on all inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can show an **algorithm** works on a Turing Machine to compute the $4x$, then you can show it is Turing computable. You can also use any TM that can be reduced to a TM as well *[Example: the double tapes, double heads and other variants]*

The really cheap way to do this is if you have a TM-complete programming language, which there are a lot of, you can just write such a program and say there exists a TM that computes this function.

Otherwise, if this is for an assignment, my guess is your professor wants you to come up with a more TM type algorithm, with tapes and a head.

Such an algorithm that's really naïve is you could mark every section of the tape all the way until you encounter where $x$ is. Then, you shift all of the marks and $x$ to the next part of the tape, essentially shifting all your $\{1, 2, \ldots, x\}$ to $\{x+1, x+2,\ldots, 2x\}$. Do this until you have $\{3x+1, 3x+2, \ldots, 4x\}$. Then, go erase every $x$ except for $4x$, and that's your output.

Comment: If you pick a turing-complete programming language L and a program P that computes 4*x, how does that prove that a Turing-machine can compute it? Turing-completeness says L is at least as powerful as a TM, but not the other way. The other direction would be an implication of Church–Turing thesis.

Comment: Sure fair, but showing the existence of an algorithm on a TM should be sufficient, or using any Turing equivalent TM variation